# Thread-safe publish with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Can I share one instance of ISubscriber for publishing messages into the same or different channels from different threads?

This is not documented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. All the key APIs in SE.Redis (the `IDatabase`, `IServer`, `ISubscriber` implementations) are fully thread-safe, with the expectation that they will be potentially shared and hammered from multiple threads.