# Making IDistributedCache thread-safe in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core, distributed-caching

I need to use `IDistributedCache` in my app and it could be `MemoryDistributedCache` or `RedisCache` as an underlying implementation. My understanding those are not thread-safe, so I created my own wrapper with usage of `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

`ReaderWriterLockSlim` allows multiple threads for reading or exclusive access for writing. And now I wonder if it's the right tool for the job and if `MemoryDistributedCache` and `RedisCache` reading methods are thread-safe.

As to overall solution - I understand it takes time to store and read values from a distributed cache like Redis. But I don't have much choice as the values I store are even slower to get and manage.

Here's the snippet:

```
...
        public async Task<byte[]> GetAsync(string key, CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken())
        {
            _cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return await _cache.GetAsync(GetCacheKey(key), token);
            }
            finally
            {
                _cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }

        public async Task SetAsync(string key, byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken())
        {
            _cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                await _cache.SetAsync(GetCacheKey(key), value, options, token);
            }
            finally
            {
                _cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(string key, CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken())
        {
            _cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                await _cache.RemoveAsync(GetCacheKey(key), token);
            }
            finally
            {
                _cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `MemoryDistributedCache` is thread safe since using MemoryCache internally.
https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Caching/Memory/src/MemoryDistributedCache.cs#L34

Comment: Thank you! But what about RedisCache?

Comment: `RedisCache` is not thread-safe. They uses `IDatabase` as a singleton.
https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src/RedisCache.cs#L166

Comment: ok, so I'm going to the right direction then. Or... not sure about reads.

Comment: I guess I'll need some tests

Comment: The StackExchange.Redis docu says:
"The object returned from GetDatabase is a cheap pass-thru object, and does not need to be stored."
  
So I would say the implementation of `RedisCache` is not quite right.

Comment: IMO all implementations of `IDistributedCache` should be thread-safe.

Comment: I guess I was wrong. `IDatabase` is thread safe.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52945926/8810910

Answer (score 7):

All `IDistributedCache` implementations should be thread-safe. If one is not, then please create a bug report to get it fixed.

Even if one of them is not thread-safe, using `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to guard `async` code is invalid. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> ReaderWriterLockSlim has managed thread affinity; that is, each Thread object must make its own method calls to enter and exit lock modes. No thread can change the mode of another thread.

The simplest workaround would be to use `SemaphoreSlim` instead of `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

Comment: Great I don't need to write anything then! But how can I ensure it actually is thread safe?

Comment: The best way would be to find it in the docs, and if that fails, ask the authors.

Comment: what if we have multiple application nodes on different servers sharing same Database and therefore share same Distributed Cache ?

Comment: @Al-HanashMoataz: I'm not sure what your question is. If you have different servers, they *should* be sharing the same distributed cache - that's the whole point of a distributed cache.

Comment: sorry did not explain well .. i ment this 'The simplest workaround would be to use SemaphoreSlim instead of ReaderWriterLockSlim' how would SemaphoreSlim prevent another thread on different server from overwriting DistributedCache based on old-modified data from same DistributedCache Server1-Thread1 gets data from cache then Server2-Thread2 gets same data from same cache then T1 overrwrite cache (T2 wont notice T1 overrwrite) then T2 overwrite the already overwrited cache

Comment: @Al-HanashMoataz: It doesn't. In the extremely unlikely case that there is a bug that makes an `IDistributedCache` non-threadsafe, then `SemaphoreSlim` can be used to work around that bug.